# Multiple OpenGL contexts, multiple windows, multithreading, and vsync

Tags: multithreading, opengl

I am creating a graphical user interface application using OpenGL in which there can be any number of windows - "multi-document interface" style.

If there were one window, the main loop could look like this:

1. handle events
2. draw()
3. swap buffers (vsync causes this to block until vertical monitor refresh)

However consider the main loop when there are 3 windows:

1. each window handle events
2. each window draw()
3. window 1 swap buffers (block until vsync)
4. (some time later) window 2 swap buffers (block until vsync)
5. (some time later) window 3 swap buffers (block until vsync)

Oops... now rendering one frame of the application is happening at 1/3 of the proper framerate.

### Workaround: Utility Window

One workaround is to have only one of the windows with vsync turned on, and the rest of them with vsync turned off. Call swapBuffers() on the vsync window first and draw that one, then draw the rest of the windows and swapBuffers() on each one.

This workaround will probably look fine most of the time, but it's not without issues:

- it is inelegant to have one window be special
- a race condition could still cause screen tearing
- some platforms ignore the vsync setting and force it to be on
- I read that switching which OpenGL context is bound is an expensive operation and should be avoided.

### Workaround: One Thread Per Window

Since there can be one OpenGL context bound per thread, perhaps the answer is to have one thread per window.

I still want the GUI to be single threaded, however, so the main loop for a 3-window situation would look like this:

(for each window)

1. lock global mutex
2. handle events
3. draw()
4. unlock global mutex
5. swapBuffers()

Will this work? This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043745/synchronizing-multiple-opengl-windows-to-vsync) indicates that it will not:

> It turns out that the windows are 'fighting' each other: it looks like
>   the SwapBuffers calls are synchronized and wait for each other, even
>   though they are in separate threads. I'm measuring the frame-to-frame
>   time of each window and with two windows, this drops to 30 fps, with
>   three to 20 fps, etc.

To investigate this claim I created a [simple test program](https://github.com/andrewrk/opengl-multi-window-test). This program creates N windows and N threads, binds one window per thread, requests each window to have vsync on, and then reports the frame rate. So far the results are as follows:

- Linux, X11, 4.4.0 NVIDIA 346.47 (2015-04-13)

  - frame rate is 60fps no matter how many windows are open.
- OSX 10.9.5 (2015-04-13)

  - frame rate is not capped; swap buffers is not blocking.

### Workaround: Only One Context, One Big Framebuffer

Another idea I thought of: have only one OpenGL context, and one big framebuffer, the size of all the windows put together.

Each frame, each window calls `glViewport` to set their respective rectangle of the framebuffer before drawing.

After all drawing is complete, swapBuffers() on the only OpenGL context.

I'm about to investigate whether this workaround will work or not. Some questions I have are:

- Will it be OK to have such a big framebuffer?
- Is it OK to call `glViewport` multiple times every frame?
- Will the windowing library API that I am using even allow me to create OpenGL contexts independent of windows?
- Wasted space in the framebuffer if the windows are all different sizes?

[Camilla Berglund](https://github.com/elmindreda), maintainer of [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) says:

> That's not how glViewport works. It's not
>   how buffer swapping works either. Each window will have a
>   framebuffer. You can't make them share one. Buffer swapping is
>   per window framebuffer and a context can only be bound to a single
>   window at a time. That is at OS level and not a limitation of
>   GLFW.

### Workaround: Only One Context

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296353/win32-opengl-vsync-and-multiple-monitors-with-different-refresh-rates) indicates that this algorithm might work:

```
Activate OpenGL context on window 1  
Draw scene in to window 1

Activate OpenGL context on window 2  
Draw scene in to window 2

Activate OpenGL context on window 3  
Draw scene in to window 3

For all Windows
SwapBuffers
```

According to the question asker,

> With V-Sync enabled, SwapBuffers will sync to the slowest monitor and
>   windows on faster monitors will get slowed down.

It looks like they only tested this on Microsoft Windows and it's not clear that this solution will work everywhere.

Also once again many sources tell me that makeContextCurrent() is too slow to have in the draw() routine.

It also looks like this is not spec conformant with EGL. In order to allow another thread to `eglSwapBuffers()`, you have to `eglMakeCurrent(NULL)` which means your `eglSwapBuffers` now is supposed to return `EGL_BAD_CONTEXT`.

### The Question

So, my question is: what's the best way to solve the problem of having a multi-windowed application with vsync on? This seems like a common problem but I have not yet read a satisfying solution for it.

### Similar Questions

Similar to this question: [Synchronizing multiple OpenGL windows to vsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043745/synchronizing-multiple-opengl-windows-to-vsync) but I want a platform-agnostic solution - or at least a solution for each platform.

And this question: [Using SwapBuffers() with multiple OpenGL canvases and vertical sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747902/using-swapbuffers-with-multiple-opengl-canvases-and-vertical-sync?rq=1) but really this problem has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: So you mean, according to your experiments, one context per thread (and window) works fine?

Answer (score 15):

> swap buffers (vsync causes this to block until vertical monitor refresh)

No, it doesn't block. The buffer swap call *may* return immediately and *not* block. What it does however is inserting a synchronization point so that execution of commands altering the back buffer is delayed until the buffer swap happened. The OpenGL command queue is of limited length. Thus once the command queue is full, futher OpenGL calls will block the program until further commands can be pushes into the queue.

Also the buffer swap *is not* an OpenGL operation. It's a graphics / windowing system level operation and happens independent of the OpenGL context. Just look at the buffer swap functions: The only parameter they take are a handle to the drawable (=window). In fact even if you have multiple OpenGL contexts operating on a single drawable, you swap the buffer only once; and you can do it without a OpenGL context being current on the drawable at all.

So the usual approach is:

```
' first do all the drawing operations
foreach w in windows:
    foreach ctx in w.contexts:
        ctx.make_current(w)
        do_opengl_stuff()
        glFlush()

' with all the drawing commands issued
' loop over all the windows and issue
' the buffer swaps.
foreach w in windows:
    w.swap_buffers()
```

Since the buffer swap does not block, you can issue all the buffer swaps for all the windows, without getting delayed by V-Sync. However the next OpenGL drawing command that addresses a back buffer issued for swapping will likely stall.

A workaround for that is using an FBO into which the actual drawing happens and combine this with a loop doing the FBO blit to the back buffer before the swap buffer loop:

```
' first do all the drawing operations
foreach w in windows:
    foreach ctx in w.contexts:
        ctx.make_current(w)
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_BUFFER, ctx.master_fbo)
        do_opengl_stuff()
        glFlush()

' blit the FBOs' renderbuffers to the main back buffer
foreach w in windows:
    foreach ctx in w.contexts:
        ctx.make_current(w)
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_BUFFER, 0)
        blit_renderbuffer_to_backbuffer(ctx.master_renderbuffer)
        glFlush()

' with all the drawing commands issued
' loop over all the windows and issue
' the buffer swaps.
foreach w in windows:
    w.swap_buffers()
```

Comment: Thank you for this very enlightening answer. Related question: People on IRC keep telling me that `ctx.make_current(w)` is "ridiculously slow" and therefore I should use one thread per context. Is this really an issue?

Comment: I used this to test your pseudocode: https://github.com/andrewrk/opengl-multi-window-test

On OSX and Windows, worked as expected. On Linux using NVIDIA 346.47 driver, I got `60 / window_count` fps.

Comment: @andrewrk: Can you check how long each call to glfwSwapBuffers takes? Anyway, on the system I'm currently sitting in front of your program reports fps = display refresh rate regardless of output. I did notice, that you ask for a debugging OpenGL context; this may make the NVidia driver to do "some" things differently. I've to double check on a NVidia system. However if everything else fails, the NVidia drivers support "swap groups" https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/SGIX/swap_group.txt

Comment: I tried turning debug off, same behavior. Each call to `glfwSwapBuffers` takes `0.0166667` seconds (1.0 / 60.0)

Comment: According to someone who works for NVIDIA on IRC, the spec does not require swap_buffers() to be async, and the most reliable way to get the desired behavior is to have one thread per window.

Comment: @andrewrk: Actually the spec can be interpreted either way. The exact wording is: `The client must synchronize the threads that perform the swap and the rendering, using some means outside the scope of GLX, to insure that each new frame is completely rendered before it is made visible` and `Subsequent OpenGL commands can be issued immediately, but will not be executed until the buffer swapping has completed, typically during vertical retrace of the display monitor`. Other than that the GLX spec says nothing. NVidia is known to interpret OpenGL specs in ways that benefit their implementation.

Comment: Using multiple threads is a viable method and remember that you don't have to make the OpenGL context current, so this cost is avoided by doing so. It comes however at the cost of the overhead of having one thread per window.

Comment: @datenwolf "No, it doesn't block. The buffer swap call returns immediately and never blocks.", sorry but with vsync enabled, blocking is the 'purpose' of wglSwapBuffers !

Comment: @Maypeur: Show me the specification where this is explicitly stated. Believe me that I was surprised, too, when I found out that the specification makes no definitive statements on SwapBuffers timing behaviour. I did measure this stuff above… not with software timers, but with oscilloscopes probing V-Sync signal to the monitor and toggling GPIO pins through a single I/O instruction injected into SwapBuffer code (one can permit user space programs to do direct I/O writes to specific addresses, see `ioperm(2)`).

Answer (score 0):

thanks @andrewrk for all theses research, i personnaly do like that :

Create first window and his opengl context with double buffer.
Active vsync on this window (swapinterval 1)

Create others windows and attach first context with double buffer.
Disable vsync on theses others window (swapinterval 0)

For each frame
For invert each window (the one with vsync enable at the end).
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, commonContext);
draw.
SwapBuffer

In that manner, i achieve the vsync and all window are based on this same vsync.

But i encoutered problem without aero : tearing...